# android in app billing security non-consumable items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing

Android doc says about the developer payload:

> but for non-consumable items you should use a string that uniquely identifies the user.

How?
I can read for example the phone number but then I need extra authorizations I don't want to add. Or I could send a request to my own server where the user has to register first - but I don't have a server and for my app it would be an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Developer payload is just an extra string which your app only can send and verify. you can create any string and send it with your request. same string you will get back in purchase response. Developer guide suggest to generate random unique developer payload for consumable product you can do same for non-consumable products also but I will suggest you if your app has any login algorithm use `loginId of user` as developer payload and if your app does not have login algorithm declare any strings and send that string as developer payload but make sure this string is **not** your(or your company) name make any combination and use.